# GMail and Outlook Attachment Not Showing in Mail after Upgrading to Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, mail.app, ms-office, gmail, attachments

I used to see Word and PDF attachements with my GMail account in Mail.  Recently I added my new Outlook account to Mail and found that attachments are missing.  So I asked my friends to send attachments to my GMail account and they are also not showing up.  All I see in attachment is a winmail.dat file (no matter my friend sends a Word or PDF file over).  This happens only after I upgraded to Mountain Lion.  Just wonder if there's some setting I need to tweak, hopefully this is not a 10.8 problem.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free online winmail.dat reader at [Winmail.dat](http://www.winmail-dat.com/online.php). The usual warnings about uploading documents to an unknown website apply, so don't use this for confidential stuff.